# Can´t install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

When I try to Install Ubuntu 14.04 either the x86 or 64 bit version (I´m using Windows 8.1) the Install process freezes after I choose Continue when asked about installing via internet some mp3 stuff. I don´t know what to do anymore. I´ve tried using a usb or dvd and the loading is still going and going but I can´t continue the Install process.

Comment: Did you try the install without asking for anything to be downloaded?  You might have a wireless problem, which is easier to fix after installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine which version your computer can handle.  Since you have 8.1 on it, I would assume that it will handle 64 bit but if you are in doubt use the 32 bit version.
2. Download the Ubuntu ISO.  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
3. Run an MD5sum check.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
4. Burn the image (do not copy) to a DVD at the lowest possible speed or create a bootable flash drive/pen drive.
5. After the burn is complete you will have a bootable DVD.  Go ahead and boot from it and choose try Ubuntu.  By doing this you will be able to try the OS without making any changes to your computer.
6. You have to decide if you want to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows or if you want to completely over-write Windows.  In either case, back up any data that you currently have on your computer to an external source, a cloud, DVDs, flash drives, another hard drive (your choice).  You may lose it so back it up.
7. All of this should be done before you think about installing.